# Why is Ruby STDOUT buffering when I don't expect it to?

Tags: ruby, pipe, stdout, jq

The following code is a simplification of my current situation. I have a JSON log source which I continuously fetch and write to stdout with `puts`.

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "json"

loop do
  puts({ value: "foobar" }.to_json)
  sleep 1
end
```

I want to be able to pipe the output of this script into `jq` for further processing, but in a 'stream'-friendly way, using unix pipes. Running the above code like so:

```sh
./my_script | jq
```

Results in an empty output. However, if I place an `exit` statement after the `sleep` call, the output is sent through the pipe to `jq` as expected. I was able to solve this problem by calling `$stdout.flush` following the `puts` call. While it's working now, I'm not sure why. `$stdout.sync` is set to `true` by default (see [`IO#sync`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-sync)). It seems to me that if sync was enabled, then Ruby should be doing no output buffering, and calling `$stdout.flush` should not be required - yet it is.

My follow-up question is about using `tail` instead of `jq`. It seems to me that I should be able to pipe a text stream into `tail` the same way I pipe it into `jq`, but neither method (with the `$stdout.flush` call or without it) works - the output is just empty.

Comment: `tail` shows you only the last N lines of the input. If input is not finished, tail cannot decide what to show.

Comment: _"$stdout.sync is set to true by default (see IO#sync)"_ – where does the documentation say so?

Comment: BTW, setting `STDOUT.sync = true` explicitly works just fine for me. By default, the output is flushed automatically if the output device is a TTY, and buffered otherwise. You can check for `STDOUT.tty?` – it's `true` when writing directly to the terminal and `false` when being piped / redirected.

Comment: ^ – you might have guessed that from IRB, where `$stdout.sync` seems to be true by default, but `ruby -e 'puts $stdout.sync'` will show what applies to your script.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Does that even make sense on a pipe? (One that doesn’t stay open after EOF, anyway.)

Comment: @Ry- turns out no, `yes | tail -f` hangs despite `man` uses “descriptor” as the input name.

Comment: @mrzasa You're right - I should have clarified I was using `tail -f`. My understanding of the `-f` flag is that it will not stop reading when reaching an EOF - and I'm not sure that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @stefan As you @Ry pointed out, I falsely convinced myself that `$stdout.sync` was enabled by default because I tested the value in IRB rather than in the context of the script. Feel free to leave an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I don't quite follow - is `tail -f` hanging in this way unexpected? What can be done to prevent the hanging, if anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ry points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421549/why-is-ruby-stdout-buffering-when-i-dont-expect-it-to#comment105030013_59421549), `$stdout.sync` is `true` by default in IRB, but this is not necessarily the same for scripts.

So you should set `$stdout.sync = true` to be sure to prevent buffering.